# Get sum of length of nested array in an object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object like this

```js
const obj = {
  name: "abc",
  arr: [{
    key1: "value1",
    arr1: [1, 2, 3]
  }, {
    key1: "value2",
    arr1: [4, 5, 6]
  }]
}
```

Here, i want to add the lengths of arrays arr1 and arr2, and return 6 as an answer. I know looping and calculating lenghts by for-in is one solution, but what can be a faster and more precise solution?

Comment: What do you mean "more precise"? Why would the proposed calculation with a `for` loop not be precise?

Comment: You can use `reduce()`. It may not be faster, and it's not as simple as a `for` loop.

Comment: It's kind of strange that each element of the array has different keys. Will it always be the case that the array in element `i` will be named `array(i+1)`?

Comment: Why is the length of `arr` not counted? What would you expect for `{arr:[1,2,{x:1}],arr2:[1,2,{arr1:[1]}]}`

Comment: @trincot sorry if i chose a bad word for it. English is not my native language. What i meant was something shorter

Comment: @Barmar you're right, that isnt the case, and i have edited the keys.

Comment: @ranieribt edited my keys. they have the same names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the simplest implementation I can think of using `reduce`

```js
const obj = {
  name: "abc",
  arr: [{
    key1: "value1",
    arr1: [1, 2, 3]
  }, {
    key1: "value2",
    arr1: [4, 5, 6]
  }]
}

const result = obj.arr.reduce((res, {arr1}) => res + arr1.length, 0)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks you want to count the lengths of arrays that only have primitive values as members, not of arrays which have (some) objects/arrays as members.

Here is a proposed recursive solution:

```js
const isPrimitive = val => Object(val) !== val;
const isArrayOfPrimitive = arr => arr?.every?.(isPrimitive);

const deepLength = obj => isPrimitive(obj) ? 0
         : Object.values(obj).reduce((sum, val) => sum + deepLength(val), 
                                     isArrayOfPrimitive(obj) ? obj.length : 0);

// Example run:
const obj = {
  name: "abc",
  arr: [{
    key1: "value1",
    arr1: [1, 2, 3]
  }, {
    key2: "value2",
    arr2: [4, 5, 6]
  }]
};

console.log(deepLength(obj)); // 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = {
    name: "abc",
    arr: [
        { key1: "value1", arr1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9] },
        { key2: "value2", arr2: [4, 5, 6] }
    ]
}



function getNumbers(arr) {
    let a = arr['arr'][0].arr1.length;
    let b = arr['arr'][1].arr2.length;

    let sum = a + b;
    return sum;
}

console.log(getNumbers(obj));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.